# PHP Regex to extract only portions of different strings

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I know there are many regex questions on Stackoverflow and I've studied my code again and again but as a newbie to regex and PHP in general I just don't understand. I have a list of file names such as

> 1000032842_WMN_2150_cv.pdf
>
> 1000041148_BKO_111_SY_bj.pdf
>
> 000048316_ED_3100_AMW_2_a.pdf
>
> 1000041231_HF_210_WPO_cr.pdf

I am trying to extract the last lowercase characters only: **`cv`**, **`bj`**, **`a`**, **`cr`**

I am using the following regex to try and do that: `[a-z.]+$`

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/zZ1sO7/3)

1) Is the regex correct ?

2) What would be the right php function to use to extra the portion of these strings ?

I have used `preg_match`, `preg_split`, but I am not sure which one I should really use. I *THINK* `preg_split` is the correct function.

```
$url = "1000036112_GKV_35_VM_32_a.pdf";
$url = preg_split('/[a-z.]+$/', $url);
print_r ($url);
```

but **`[1]`** is empty.

```
Array ( [0] => 1000036112_GKV_35_VM_32_ [1] => )
```

---

**UPDATE EDIT**

The following gives a list of int 0, int 1, etc.

```
<?php
    $filename = "urls.csv";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    if ($handle !== FALSE) {
        while (($data=fgetcsv($handle,99999,',')) !== FALSE) {
            $url = $data[1];
            var_dump (preg_match_all('/_([a-z]{1,2})\./', $url));
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
[a-z]+(?=\.pdf)
```

Where `(?=\.pdf)` is a "[lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)" regex, basically selects one or more letters `[a-z]` if there's **`.pdf`** after them

[**Regex101-1**](https://regex101.com/r/kA4qD9/1)

---

If you'll have other extensions beside **`.pdf`** then use this regex which will use lookahead and lookbehind to grab strings preceded by **`_`** and followed by a dot **`.`**

```
(?<=_)[a-z]+(?=\.)
```

[**Regex101-2**](https://regex101.com/r/dW9gP0/2)

---

Getting the needed strings using PHP:

[**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2dc2-3wb6) - *hit* "Run" *or* F9 *to see the result*

```
$urls = array('1000032842_WMN_2150_cv.pdf', '1000041148_BKO_111_SY_bj.pdf', '000048316_ED_3100_AMW_2_a.pdf', '1000041231_HF_210_WPO_cr.pdf');

foreach($urls as $url) {
  if (preg_match('/(?<=_)[a-z]+(?=\.)/i', $url, $match)) {
    echo $match[0].'<br>';
  }
}
```

Output:

> cv
>   bj
>   a
>   cr

Comment: This will actually select 1-infinite caracters before `.pdf` which means it won't stop at 2

Comment: I don't see where in the OP he said there'll be only 1 or 2 letters

Comment: thanks, I Think I'm really getting on the right track now. It's just that the urls are in a csv file and so far i'm getting 'int 1' or int 0 as results. I'm not using this the right way... Please check my code: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2dc2-3wb6

Comment: that's the same link in my answer :D, however just replace the code you have in your question with this `$url = "1000036112_GKV_35_VM_32_a.pdf"; $url = preg_match('/(?<=_)[a-z]+(?=\.)/i', $url, $match); echo $match[0].'<br>';` [**PHP Fiddle**](http://www.phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zjyc-19v8)

Comment: Woops sorry for the bad link! :) Correct one here: http://collabedit.com/q8uea I can't be too far from finding the right code. Yes your regex is definitely correct.

Answer (score 1):

### [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/bB1sP8/1)

```
_(?<your_group_name>[a-z]{1,2})\.
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IWcBtElo4OI_vEkg)

### PHP

```
<?php
    $matches = array(); 
    preg_match_all(
        '/_([a-z]{1,2})\./', 
        "1000032842_WMN_2150_cv.pdf

1000041148_BKO_111_SY_bj.pdf

000048316_ED_3100_AMW_2_a.pdf

1000041231_HF_210_WPO_cr.pdf", 
        $matches
    ); 
    var_dump($matches);
?>
```

### Result

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "_cv."
    [1]=>
    string(4) "_bj."
    [2]=>
    string(3) "_a."
    [3]=>
    string(4) "_cr."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "cv"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "bj"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "cr"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you have already accepted an answer, why not come up with sth. as simple as:

```
_([a-z]+)
```

For your code, this would come down to:

```
<?php
$filename = "urls.csv";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$regex = '~_([a-z]+)~';
if ($handle !== FALSE) {
    while (($data=fgetcsv($handle,99999,',')) !== FALSE) {
        $url = $data[1];
        preg_match_all($regex, $url, $matches);
        // your matches are in the $matches array
    }
}
?>
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hA7sN3/1).